# Intellij Debug Docker container keeps giving me IO Exception Handshake Failed

Tags: java, docker, debugging, docker-compose, jdb

I am trying to setup a remote debugger in Intellij v2020.1, I keep getting the error below:

Unable to open debugger port (localhost:5005): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"

In my docker compose file I have mounted port 5005 to 5005

In my docker file i have:

`EXPOSE 5005`

`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "runme.sh"]`

and in my shell script I have:

`/opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar mine.jar`

When I do a docker ps, i can see the below:

`0.0.0.0:5005->5005/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8111->8111/tcp`

In IntelliJ I setup the remote debugger from port 5005 to contaier port 5005, added in the module claspath and in the before launch step, added in my compose file.

The service starts up fine, but jut cant connect to the debugger, any ideas?

Comment: Does `jdb -attach 5005` work?

Comment: where do I place that?

Comment: `jdb` is the command line debugger provided with the JDK, you run this command in the terminal on the host system. See also https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdb/jdb_quick_guide.htm. This will help to understand if the issue has anything to do with IntelliJ IDEA. In case `jdb` also fails, then the issue is with some networking configuration between the host and Docker. Also, what Java version do you use in Docker? If it's Java 9+, the command line to enable debugging should look like this: `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005` so that it binds on all interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried this on the host system and also get the same error, so its not an IntelliJ issue.  I am using Jdk8

Comment: Also tracked at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173607 with no solution found so far.

Comment: I switched the port to something else, and it has started working.  Thanks for the help

Comment: agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 works for OpenJDK 11.
Thanks!

Comment: @CrazyCoder I assume jdb -attach 5005 should work? I get Unable to attach to target VM.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-and-debug-a-spring-boot-application-using-docker-compose.html#53c9c47c just tested from this  - jdb -attach 5005 gives exception but the code is stopped at breakpoints in demo application.

Answer (score 17):

Placing this line in my Dockerfile solved it for me:

```
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
```

The critical part here, being the "address=*:5005" and *not* simply "address=5005". Apparently some security changes since Java 9 requires the *: before the port.

EDIT: I see you're on Java 8. But perhaps adding *-XDebug* to the options as well, could do the trick:

```
ENV JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
```

Comment: -Xdebug is for <= JDK 1.4

Comment: That's the first think i did. doesn't work neither from jdb nor from IDEA - handshake failed - connection prematurely closed